# Main page with System.NotImplementedException error

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin

I get a System.NotImplementedException error whenever I try to launch the page on the emulator that takes photographs. Whenever I attempt to take a photo with the emulator's camera, I get taken to the main page in the Xamarin Studio project that launches the user interface. I get the error:

System.NotImplementedException has been thrown

This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

Here is the code:

```
using UIKit;

namespace Relate.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* if you want to use a different Application Delegate class 
               from "AppDelegate" you can specify it here. */
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Here is the code for the camera. I added Media Plugin to my project.

```
using System;
using Relate.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Media;

namespace Relate.Views
{
    public partial class EditMemberPage : ContentPage
    {
        public EditMemberPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            saveButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                  if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && 
CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                  {
                      // Supply media options for saving our photo after 
it's taken.
                      var mediaOptions = new 
Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                      {
                          Directory = "Receipts",
                          Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg"
                      };

                      // Take a photo of the business receipt.
                      var file = await 
CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);
                  }
              };
        }

        async void SaveButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var famMemberItem = (FamMember)BindingContext;
            await App.Database.SaveFamMemberAsync(famMemberItem);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you installed the NuGet package in BOTH the platform projects AND the shared projects?

Comment: is that all the code?

Comment: @MattBeldon, that is all the code for the main page. Should I add the code for the edit page?

Comment: @Jason, I just updated all my NuGet packages.

Comment: add the code where the actual camera access occurs

Comment: @Jason if I understand correctly they're not using code to take a photo, they're using the camera app on the emulator.

Comment: @Matt Beldon Yes.

Comment: No, they are using the CrossMedia plugin.  I repeat my earlier question - do you have this plugin installed in BOTH your iOS project and your shared Forms project?

Comment: I do not know what a shared Forms project is but I added Media Picker to my project.

Comment: I added Media Picker to my iOS and my shared forms.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here should explain why this is not working for you: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93536/error-while-accessing-camera

You cannot access platform specific features using portable common libraries. If you want to access your emulators camera you'll have to use something like Media Plugin
            https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: That is what I did. Would you look at the updated post? It shows my code for the camera.